# Failed: Unexpected directive 'NewPracticeQuestionComponent' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular6, angular-test

I am unit-testing a commponent which uses two other components. The other components are created when button is clicked

`.html`

```
    <div id="homepage-top-div" class="homepage-component-css-grid-container">  ...
        <button id="get-question-list-button" [routerLink]="questionListRouterLink" class="btn content-div__button--blue css-grid-item-button-div btn-sm">See Questions</button>
      </div>
      <div id="practice-component-top-div" class="css-grid-container-div common-styles-div--white"> <!-- 4 rows, 1 column-->
...
        <button id="new-question-button" [routerLink]="newQuestionRouterLink"  class="btn content-div__button--blue css-grid-item-button-div btn-sm">Create a Question</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

`.ts`

```
export class HomepageContentComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  public questionListRouterLink="/practice-question-list";
  public newQuestionRouterLink="/new-practice-question";


  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I created a `spec` but I get the following error when I run it - `Failed: Unexpected directive 'NewPracticeQuestionComponent' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.`

The spec is

```
import {async, ComponentFixture, fakeAsync, TestBed, tick} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HomepageContentComponentComponent } from './homepage-content-component.component';
import {RouterTestingModule} from "@angular/router/testing";
import {AppRoutingModule} from "../app-routing.module";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import {routes} from '../app-routing.module';
import {NewPracticeQuestionComponent} from "../new-practice-question/new-practice-question.component";
import {PraticeQuestionListComponent} from "../pratice-question-list/pratice-question-list.component";
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {AppModule} from "../app.module";

fdescribe('HomepageContentComponentComponent', () => {
  let component: HomepageContentComponentComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HomepageContentComponentComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports:[
        AppModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes),
        NewPracticeQuestionComponent,
        PraticeQuestionListComponent
      ],
      declarations: [ HomepageContentComponentComponent,
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomepageContentComponentComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should navigate to New Questions Component when New Question button is clicked',fakeAsync(()=>{
    let router:Router;
    let location:Location;
    router = TestBed.get(Router);
    location = TestBed.get(Location);
    console.log('initial router is ',router);
    console.log('initial location is ',location);
    router.initialNavigation();
    router.navigate(['new-practice-question']);
    tick();
    console.log('new router is ',router);
    console.log('new location is ',location);

    expect(location.pathname).toBe('/new-practice-question');
  }));
});
```

Comment: just noticed that the Components are imported, not declared. Maybe that is the issue. I'll change it

Answer (score 7):

the issue was that `NewQuestionComponent` and `PracticeListComponent` should have been in `declarations`, not `imports`